# TS 2008 - Remote session - Black screen on logon

Tags: terminal-server, windows-sbs-2011, windows-terminal-services

2 out of 8 sites have reported not been able to connect to the network this morning, everybody excluding head office use terminal services, i have 2 2008 servers in a pool/farm. My network Cisco and my Cisco partner has already confirmed the network is fine (i can keep solid PINGS on server/machines at other sites too)

No matter what i try (CTRL + ALT + END) also changing resolution and common settings i cannot get the screen to come up.

Some get black screen, some get logon screen. and when logon get a black screen. I've tried logging them off remotely also fresh users + admin accounts

They can connect via our Remote desktop gateway... just not across the network?

help
:(

to conclude:
Cisco is apparently fine (i can VNC to their PC's!)
I can Ping and print from their site.
Other remote users are unaffected.
black screen?!?!
PCs, Laptops + Thin clients having the issue,
XP through to windows 7.
licenses O K
SBS2011

Comment: A black screen on Terminal Services / Remote Desktop Services almost always indicates high load or resource contention on the server.

Comment: both TS have been restarted during day, going to restart SBS in about 1 hour once company is closed

Answer (score 1):

rebooted everything seemed to of resolved